# Foreign Keys refering to non-existing items

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am not sure how to name my scenario properly apperantly as visible, but here is the situation:

I got multiple tables where data is inside and an application layer that inserts, deletes and updates the data.
A requirement is that i am able to log all changes entirely. To do this, i created a huge `Log` class that contains all classes that require logging.

The thing is: The log entries are never allowed to be deleted so that, if needed, i can recreate whatever was deleted (requires to identify all log entries for a given deleted type).

Example code:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Log
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TagFK))]
    public Tag Tag { get; set; } }
    public int? TagFK { get; set; } }
}
```

TL;DR:

- Log Table with FKs
- Log entries need to be always existing while their related entry might get deleted.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem fully, but I don't see why you need a FK from the log to the other tables.  The log table should be standalone, and independent from the rest.

Comment: mostly to be able to just use `from log in dbcontext.Logs where ... select log`

Comment: You still will be, but the queries will be (perhaps) slower due to lack of indices.

Comment: so you would propose to add everything with no real relation but rather adding Indexes on all of those?

Comment: Indeed.  I would also propose to delay adding indexes until you are certain you need them.  In practice, you will be searching for log changes within a certain period of time.  You will need an index by the date of the log record, and perhaps on the type of entity being logged.  

I have implemented a similar case in a CRM system and performance is ok, even tough our log has already more than 1 million records.

Comment: in EF core, it is possible to specify ON DELETE SET NULL with ReferentialAction.SetNull (see https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship). Otherwise you'll have to manually nullify the FK on deletion, since EF does not allow (mapped) single navigation properties without FK constraint, or remove the FK constraint altogether.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro the idea is to keep those but then without anything behind it. Weak navigation properties if one wants to call them like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a trigger a DB to add entry into log table before insert update and delete.
2. Use a user to connect to DB which only has insert access to the log table and not delete or update.
3. Better to create a log table per table if you really want to restore at some time.